# How can I add a SQL result of a PHP statement (fromMySQL) in an existing HTML file

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an html file that contains a table with table rows

```
<table style="width:auto">
    <tr>
       <td contenteditable="true"><select id="so"></select></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have a PHP that selects from mySQL DB and returns username

```
if ($results->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
        $name=$row["first_name"];
        echo "<option>
                 $name
              </option>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

I am trying to incorporate the result of the php into my index.html file within the table so that the option shows up in the table

How can I get the data from PHP into an already built html table row?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can either place the results into an object you can echo out in the middle of your table code or use something like AJAX to retrieve the data and place the data into your table using JavaScript.

Comment: If you want to add content, after the html page is already loaded by your visitor, you only can do that with an asynchrone javascript call (ajax).  Please provide some more code and explanation about what you want.

Answer (score 0):

for this work you should use ajax to load data in html file ...

you can do it with javascript :
create a function for load your php file :

```
function loadAjax(address,elementId) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", address, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

after create it you can use it when you want (for example after load of page). you should pass address of your php file and id of html element that you want the answer load into it .

for more learn : 
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. It should include, if possible, an example of the code to be used.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of methods that can be used here. If the HTML and PHP are in the same file you could do this:

```
<?php
if ($results->num_rows > 0) {
    $options = ''; // declare the variable to hold the options
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
        $name=$row["first_name"];
        $options .= "<option>$name</option>"; // add the options to the variable
    }
} else {
    $options = "0 results";
}
?>
```

And then add the `$options` to the HTML:

```
<table style="width:auto">
    <tr>
       <td contenteditable="true">
           <select id="so">
               <?php echo $options; ?>
           </select>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Another option, though not as neat, is to embed the PHP in the HTML:

```
<table style="width:auto">
    <tr>
       <td contenteditable="true">
           <select id="so">
    <?php
    if ($results->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
            $name=$row["first_name"];
            echo "<option>
                     $name
                  </option>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    ?>

           </select>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Yet another option would be to use AJAX to call the PHP from the HTML page and return the results to the right location. For instance, if you wanted to use jQuery you could [follow a tutorial](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html) to learn the basics and then apply that to your code.

Comment: Why he should mix HTML and PHP, if I is not necessary ?

Comment: He doesn't have to @PrafullaKumarSahu. I have included an AJAX tutorial that he might use to learn AJAX methods and then apply to their situation. The upshot is that there is more than one method to accomplish what the OP is asking.

Comment: Is it not better to use PDO and a class to get the job done ?

Comment: It is hard to determine exactly which API the OP is using to get the data and it is not always necessary to instantiate a class to get these things done.

Comment: I am not saying necessary , I am asking which is better, to use raw code snipers or class and objects ?

Comment: It is totally dependent upon the situation.

Comment: if it needs repetition , it is better to use class and functions and if for a single instance, we can use snippets , am I correct ?

Comment: Like I said, it is totally dependent on the situation. Where possible you should exercise whatever means needed to maintain the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) methodology.

Comment: I am still not getting any entries in the dropdown.
My PHP and Html are 2 separate files.

Comment: If they are two separate files you will have to use either AJAX *or* you can include the PHP file in the HTML if your server will interpret HTML as PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Two way to get the job done:-

1)Use a class, that is you should, and using its object you can retrieve the data and use it on the webpage .

ex:-  see [this class](https://gist.github.com/PrafullaKumarSahu/70daaa985f885c3421f8), it needs a lot of improvements and changes, but still can give you some idea . I am also trying to learn PDO well, not a PRO, but can be helpful to you.Comments on this class will help you get the idea .

2)Using AJAX, You can request for this data on loading the document or you can request it via get, post, request.. on any event.If you know ajax, you can use that class and ajax, or if you do not have an idea about AJAX, you can get a lot of resources to learn ajax. after this if you need my assistant, I will try to help you.

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. It should include, if possible, an example of the code to be used.

Comment: Visit the gist code I have asked to visit, the class contains some comments on it.

Comment: You should post code here, so that it is preserved for future visitors to SO.

Comment: If code is too much lengthy is it still recommendable to post here ?

Comment: Probably not, but if the OP and other visitors do not have Git access they will not be able to view your code.

Comment: I was not having git access, just learned to use it as I feel , it is good for programmers, they will also feel the same, I guess.

Comment: That will not always be the case.

Comment: may be, but what you will suggest , programmers should learn to use it or totally no need of this .

Comment: Not everyone who posts a question is a programmer or will version their code or want to learn how to use Git. We cannot and should not try to force them to.

Comment: if some is coding, I should consider him as user or coder ?

Comment: If you read the tons of PHP posts on this site you will read a great number of them that begin with *"I am not a coder or programmer,  but...."*